# AWS Lambda Function - Image Upload - Process Review

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, socket.io, aws-lambda

I'm trying to better understand how the overall flow should work with AWS Lambda and my Web App.

I would like to have the client upload a file to a public bucket (completely bypassing my API resources), with the client UI putting it into a folder for their account based on a GUID. From there, I've got lambda to run when it detects a change to the public bucket, then resizing the file and placing it into the processed bucket.

However, I need to update a row in my RDS Database.

**Issue**

I'm struggling to understand the best practice to use for identifying the row to update. Should I be uploading another file with the necessary details (where every image upload consists really of two files - an image and a json config)? Should the image be processed, and then the client receives some data and it makes an API request to update the row in the database? What is the right flow for this step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **pre-signed URL** for the upload. This allows your application to put restrictions on the upload, such as file type, directory and size. It means that, when the file is uploaded, you already know who did the upload. It also prevents people from uploading randomly to the bucket, since it does not need to be public.

The upload can then use an Amazon S3 Event to trigger the Lambda function. The filename/location can be used to identify the user, so the database can be updated at the time that the file is processed.

See: [Uploading Objects Using Presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid uploading a file directly to S3 bypassing the API. Uploading file from your API allows you to control type of file, size etc as well as you will know who exactly is uploading the file (API authid or user id in API body). This is also a security risk to open a bucket to public for writes.

Your API clients can then upload the file via API, which then can store file on S3 (trigger another lambda for processing) and then update your RDS with appropriate meta-data for that user.